# Fill values based on adjacent column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How could I create `create_col`? For each row, find the previous time where that fruit was mentioned and check if the wanted column was yes?

```
    wanted    fruit   create_col
0   yes       apple                
1             pear       
2             peear           < last time pear was mentioned, wanted was not yes, so blank
3             apple    True   < last time apple was mentioned, wanted was yes, so True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df
###
  wanted  fruit
0    yes  apple
1          pear
2    yes   pear
3         apple
4         mango
5          pear
```

```
df['cum_list'] = df[df['wanted'].eq('yes')]['fruit'].cumsum()
df['cum_list'] = df['cum_list'].shift(1).ffill()
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

df['create_col'] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x['fruit'] in x['cum_list'], axis=1),True, '')
df.drop(columns=['cum_list'],inplace=True)
df
###
  wanted  fruit create_col
0    yes  apple           
1          pear           
2    yes   pear           
3         apple       True
4         mango           
5          pear       True
```